# Запятая между согласованными и несогласованными определениями

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли здесь запятая?

...комбинированные прокладки (металлические восьмиугольного и овального сечения)...

Comment: Судя вот по этому http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=105 запятая все-таки ставится, как я и думала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Однородными являются определения, если первое выражено согласованым прилагательным, а второе является несогласованным определением (Она сняла со стола толстую, с бахромой скатерь...). В Вашем предложении имено такие определения. Кроме того, однородны определения, стоящие после определяемого слова (прокладки металлические, восьмиугольного и овального сечения)

Comment: Да, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае только постпозиция переводит неоднородные определения в однородные: "Здесь используются комбинированные  прокладки (металлические, восьмиугольного и овального сечения)".
Но в препозиции: "Здесь используются металлические восьмиугольного и овального сечения прокладки".

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Согласованные и несогласованные определения могу быть неоднородными, если они обозначают разные признаки, не связанные общей темой, например:

У стены стоял старинный деревянный с инкрустацией шкаф.

На стол поставили синие с позолотой по краю чашки.

Стена была облицована светлым с розовыми прожилками мрамором.